# how to store content that is displayed dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I was wondering what is the proper way of store in html content that is displayed dynamically.

My case is that depending on what is clicked some sort of text is displayed in another part of a website. My first idea was to create a variable in js/jquery script to store this content so the script can access it whenever it is necessary.

this is an example:

```
var someContent=" Content to be displayed when something is clicked";
var a=$('#myid');

a.click(function(){
    $('#myOtherId').text(someContent);      
    });
```

But after a while it came to my mind that the content should be stored in the html with a display value set to 'none' and js script should simple toggle its visibility depending wether it has been clicked or not.

Storing the content in js script seems much easier - but something tells me that there is better way to do it...

Comment: So did you have a go with the display `none`? There are lots of examples out there...

Comment: yes. Maybe I should have asked my question differently: Is it a good idea or practice to store html content in js variables for dynamic display purposes.

Comment: Well that is a matter of opinion really. So that would not be a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Point taken. But as I understand there are no reasons I shouldn't do it besides my own opinion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you can do it by having the text in an HTML element, and use either jQuery's `.toggle` or `.show` depending on how you want it to respond to a second click:

```js
$("#toggle").click(function () {
    $('#msg').toggle(); // or .show() to have it in one way only
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="msg" style="display:none">Content to be displayed when something is clicked</span>
<br>
<button id="toggle">click me</button>
```

When the content is static, it seems more natural to have it embedded in your HTML, while when the content is dynamic (i.e. it depends on the actual state of the application), you would inject the dynamic part of the text with JavaScript.

For a non-JS-programmer in the development team (but with knowledge of HTML) it would in theory be easier to manipulate the messages when they are embedded in the HTML part of the page.

But this is a matter of opinion really.

Here is a mix of the two:

```js
$("#enter").click(function () {
    // Copy the number into the error message
    $('#num').text($("#inp").val());
    // Show the error message when the number is not even
    $('#msg').toggle($('#inp').val() % 2 !== 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter an even number: <input id="inp" type="number" value=1>
<button id="enter">Verify</button>

<div id="msg" style="display:none; color:red">
    The number <span id="num"></span> is not even
</div>
```